# How to copy data of specfic employee to other sheet matching employee id

Tags: vba, copy

I have data of employees of 1000 people but I need only 400 people, 400 phone numbers, to another sheet. I had all the employees ids in the other sheet. I tried vlookup but it didn't work.

```
sub trandsfer ()
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

for a=2 To 1000
for b=2 To 400

if Worksheets(1).Range("A")=Worksheets(2).Range("A") Then
worksheets(1).Range("F").Copy
Worksheets(2).Activate
Worksheets(2).Range("C").select
Select.paste
worksheets(1).activate
End if
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What did not work when you used the vlookup?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  Sub trandsfer()

            'Go through the sheets(2) Ids
            For i = 2 To 400

                idToSearch = Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 1).Value 'put the id in a variable
                'search for the id in sheet(1)
                Set findID = Worksheets(1).Columns("A").Find(what:=idToSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)

                If findID Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print "Not Found !"
                'If found
                Else
                    firstAddress = findID.Address
                    foundRow = findID.Row
                    'copy the value of column F of sheet(1) and paste it in column C of sheet(2)
                    Worksheets(1).Cells(foundRow, 6).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 3)

                End If

            Next i

   End Sub
```